# Does NSCache persist between launches?

Tags: ios, xcode, persistence, archiving, nscache

I'm looking into a fairly simple mechanism for caching and and currently using NSCache (for the reason of memory management). Question is - does the cache persist between launches? It seems like no to me.

I get objects put in cache just fine and can take them out of the cache while the app is running no problem. But once I relaunch, seems like the cache is gone.

So is there a way to make the cache persist between launches? If so, how would you re-sync the cache from previous session to the current?

Comment: Check it out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14262592/887576 It may help you.

Comment: hmm interesting, I might have to experiment. I ended up writing my own caching system that uses nsdictionaries and get cleared each restart, which is fine for my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCache` does **not** persist between launches- if you'd like to save the cache, I'd recommend simply saving the data using `CoreData`- although if memory management is an issue, then perhaps you'd be saving too much. It truly depends on what you're developing.

Comment: too bad, will use keyedArchiver for now